# Междометие "ей" — значение

Tags: значение-слов, междометие

"Ей-ей" говорят, когда хотят что-то подтвердить, в значении "точно тебе говорю". Но, например, в церковнославянском оно употребляется, скорее, при обращении, в значении "О". А какое все-таки точно значение у этого междометия?

Comment: https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/448083/%d0%a4%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%b7%d0%b5%d0%be%d0%bb%d0%be%d0%b3%d0%b8%d0%b7%d0%bc%d1%8b-%d0%b5%d0%b9-%d0%b1%d0%be%d0%b3%d1%83-%d0%b8-%d0%b8%d1%81%d1%82%d0%b8%d0%bd%d0%bd%d1%8b%d0%b9-%d0%b1%d0%be%d0%b3-%d1%82%d0%be%d0%b6%d0%b4%d0%b5%d1%81%d1%82%d0%b2%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%bd%d1%8b

Answer (score 5, accepted):

"[Ей](http://www.orthodic.org/?searchCs=&searchRu=%D0%B5%D0%B9&go.x=0&go.y=0&type=ru)" в церковно-славянском означает "истинно", "да", "так". Именно в этом значении и используется в молитвах. В общем-то в такое же значение и у русских фразеологизмов с этим словом.

Answer (score 10):

Междометие "ей-ей" - то же, что и "ей-богу". Употребляется со значением уверения.

Comment: А как же тогда упомянутое церковнославянское? В молитвах, например, "ей" употребляется при обращении к святому.

Comment: Именно при обращении? Что-то я не могу сориентироваться...
Вообще-то значение "ей" в ЦСЯ достаточно широкое, но чтобы при *обращении*...

Comment: @behemothus, ну, чего придираться? Выражение "Ей, Господи Царю", довольно легко принять за звательный "О, Господи", что даже кое-где так и переводят, например, [здесь](http://www.hram-evenkya.ru/novosti/pokayannaya-molitva-svyatogo-efrema-sirina). Хотя конечно правильней "Истинно, Господи - Царь"

Comment: Это и есть звательный.  
Но "Ей" здесь **не** при обращении. Это заверение типа "говорю правду".

Comment: Спасибо большое за разъяснения! Я тоже думала, что в молитвах "ей" употребляется в значении "О". Но можно ли тогда считать его междометием?

Comment: Да больше-то нечем...
Но вообще я залезу в какого-нибудь Гамановича - и посмотрю как он трактует.

Answer (score 0):

И у Крылова в "Демьяновой ухе"("Ушица, ей-же-ей, на славу сварена!") употребляется со значением уверения

Answer (score 0):

Это , если можно так сказать, всеобщее слово, выражающее согласие. Русск(ц.слав): ей; Англ: yes, yeah; Нем: ja; Казах: иә; Алт: эйе; Эстон: jah; Монг: тийм ээ; Словен:  ja; Армн: ayo [айо]; Кор: ye [йе]; Чуваш: ийя; Крымсктатр: э.

Comment: Довольно наивно считать общими совершенно разные слова из разных даже языковых семей.

Answer (score 0):

Утвердительно-восклицательная частица.

Острожская библия
Мф.5:37 Буди же слово ваше. ей, ей. ни, ни, лихо еже сею, отъ неприазни есть

Но да будет слово ваше: «да, да»; «нет, нет»; а что сверх этого, то от лукавого.

Comment: Отчасти правильно. А вот «так», «подлинно», — тоже восклицательные?