# Фразеологизмы "ей богу" и "истинный бог" тождественны?

Tags: этимология, фразеология

Фразеологизмы *ей богу* и *истинный бог* тождественны?

Answer (score 1):

Нет. У Преображенского частица" ей" действительно тождественна наречиям "так", "истинно".  Но Бог здесь призывается в качестве свидетеля того, что разказчик не врет, на это указывает окончание "у". Иногда, для пущей убедительности, добавляется:"Вот те крест!" - и сопровождается характерным жестом.

Comment: кто второму фразеологизму это вроде тоже относится https://phraseology.academic.ru/330/%D0%98%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B9_%D0%B1%D0%BE%D0%B3